# 3 displays, 2 connected to GPU, one connected to motherboard

Tags: ati, multiple-monitors, display, radeon

I have 3 displays, 2 connected to the GPU (it is an AMD HD 6790, DVI and HDMI connectors), and another one using my mobo's VGA connector (the one you use when you don't have a dedicated graphics card).

In windows I can have all of them working perfectly well, but in Xubuntu only the ones that are connected to my GPU work. I am using the binary drivers provided by amd.

What should I do to make them all work? Thanks.